# Confusion regarding Runnable and Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I know this is a very tiny thing and would be quite easy for all you programmers out here, but I am stuck. I am not able to understand why this code snippet is printing out "Dog" instead of "Cat".

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Cat");
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(r) {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Dog");
    }
};

t.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `start()` on a `Thread` object causes the JVM to spawn a new system thread which then proceeds to call the `run` method. Its default implementation looks something like this :

```
private Runnable target; // This is what you passed to the constructor

@Override
public void run() {
  if (target != null) {
    target.run();
  }
}
```

Since you have overriden this very method in your anonymous `Thread` subclass declaration, this code never gets called, and the `Runnable` you injected is simply never used.

Also, whenever possible, [leave the `Thread` class alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread) and put your code in `Runnable`s instead.